# How to use conditional validation with devexpress in Asp.net core razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, razor-pages

can you give me an example how it is possible to use conditional validation with devexpress in Asp.net core razor page? For example I have a devexpress checkbox and if it is activated, the validation must be set on another field. If deactivated the validation should be deactivated from another field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 item.AddSimpleFor(m => m.AplicaInteres).ColSpan(1).Label(l => l.Text("Aplicar interés")).Editor(e=>e.CheckBox().OnValueChanged("chkInteresChanged"));
                item.AddSimpleFor(m => m.TasaInteres).ColSpan(1).Label(l => l.Text("Tasa de Interés")).Editor(e=>e.NumberBox().ShowSpinButtons(true).Mode(NumberBoxMode.Number).Format("#,##0.##").StylingMode(EditorStylingMode.Outlined));


function chkInteresChanged(e) {           
        vform.getEditor("TasaInteres").option("disabled", !e.value);
        vform.getEditor("TasaInteres").option("value", 0);            
    }
```

And add a Custom Validation to the field TasaInteres like this:

```
 [CustomCuotaValidator]
public decimal? TasaInteres { get; set; } = 0;
```

And here is the code of the Custom Validator
https://github.com/rmlarios/PayLotsClientAPI/blob/DevExpressReporting/Data/CustomValidations/CustomTasaCambioValidator.cs